# Refresh java program after submitting information to database

Tags: java, mysql

I created a Java address book program using MySQL Database. My program has a left panel and a right panel. The left panel writes new entries to the database and the right panel displays all the database info. I'm having trouble updating the program after I've submitted new entries to the database. I have to close my program then reopen it to display the new info.

How can I get my address book to update itself after I click the submit button?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Address Book Input");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("MySQL Address Book");

JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

JTextField $first_name = new JTextField(20);
JTextField $last_name = new JTextField(20);
JTextField $phone = new JTextField(20);
JTextField $email = new JTextField(20);
JTextField $street = new JTextField(20);
JTextField $city = new JTextField(20);
JTextField $state = new JTextField(20);
JTextField $zip = new JTextField(20);

JLabel first_nameLabel = new JLabel("First Name: ");
JLabel last_nameLabel = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
JLabel phoneLabel = new JLabel("Phone: ");
JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email: ");
JLabel streetLabel = new JLabel("Street: ");
JLabel cityLabel = new JLabel("City: ");
JLabel stateLabel = new JLabel("State: ");
JLabel zipLabel = new JLabel("Zip: ");

public Frame1() {
    super("1 Class Template");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800, 480);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    initComponents();

}

public void initComponents() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel panelRight = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel addressBook = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    add(panel);
    panel.add(panelLeft);
    panel.add(panelRight);
    panelRight.add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(addressBook);

    panelLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    panelRight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    label1.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 18));
    gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panelLeft.add(label1, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(first_nameLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(last_nameLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(phoneLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(emailLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(streetLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(cityLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(stateLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add(zipLabel, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panelLeft.add($first_name, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add($last_name, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add($phone, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add($email, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add($street, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add($city, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add($state, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;
    panelLeft.add($zip, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy++;
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                java.sql.Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name",
                        "user_name", "password");

                Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
                myStmt
                        .executeUpdate("INSERT INTO address_book (first_name, last_name, phone, email, street, city, state, zip) VALUES ('"
                                + $first_name.getText()
                                + "', '"
                                + $last_name.getText()
                                + "', '"
                                + $phone.getText()
                                + "', '"
                                + $email.getText()
                                + "', '"
                                + $street.getText()
                                + "', '"
                                + $city.getText()
                                + "', '"
                                + $state.getText()
                                + "', '"
                                + $zip.getText() + "') ");

                $first_name.setText("");
                $last_name.setText("");
                $phone.setText("");
                $email.setText("");
                $street.setText("");
                $city.setText("");
                $state.setText("");
                $zip.setText("");

                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "Your Data Has been Inserted", "Result",
                        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            }

            catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    panelLeft.add(submit, gbc);

    label2.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 18));
    gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    addressBook.add(label2, gbc);

    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    try {
        java.sql.Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name", "user_name",
                "password");

        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        ResultSet myRs = myStmt
                .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM address_book ORDER BY last_name, first_name");

        while (myRs.next()) {
            JLabel lab1 = new JLabel(myRs.getString("first_name") + " "
                    + myRs.getString("last_name"));
            JLabel lab2 = new JLabel(myRs.getString("phone"));
            JLabel lab3 = new JLabel(myRs.getString("email"));
            JLabel lab4 = new JLabel(myRs.getString("street"));
            JLabel lab5 = new JLabel(myRs.getString("city") + ", "
                    + myRs.getString("state") + " " + myRs.getString("zip"));

            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridy++;
            addressBook.add(lab1, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            addressBook.add(lab2, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            addressBook.add(lab3, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            addressBook.add(lab4, gbc);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 20, 4);
            gbc.gridy++;
            addressBook.add(lab5, gbc);

        }
    }

    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Frame1();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Believe in SQL-Injection sir. just as you read and fill up the panel for displaying data, do the same thing at the end of inserting data. If the back-end database would do any extra operation by data insert event(trigger), reloading the whole display panel give you a good peace in mind about updated data.

Comment: Separate your areas of responsibility so that the UI is separate from your data and the management of the data, this means that when you want to update the data, you ask the UI for it and update it any manner you want and when you want to update the UI you pass it the data it needs

Comment: @MadProgrammer In what manner would you suggest I separate the UI from the data? I'm not having any luck

Comment: @user5266804 I tried reloading the display panel through recalling the initComponents method in my submit button. I get something strange with old information and new updated information overlapping. This would be a good way to do it if I can remove the old information.

Comment: @DaleWahl no sir, wrong method as calling `init` again, you just ned to extract the filling method in a method, and call that method each time, but before filling, remove all existing stuffs, then ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code I was looking for. This clears the addressBook panel, then I can pull my info from the database again.

```
    addressBook.removeAll();
    addressBook.updateUI();
```

Answer (score 3):

After inserting data from your left panel, just call a function that will contain the code to set the updated the data with the new text like

```
lab1.setText($first_name);
..
..
```

then put `$first_name` to

```
null
```

Comment: This is not clearing the old data so I'm getting duplicate set of data when I try this.

Comment: Old data of what `lab1` ? `lab1.setText($first_name);` will overwrite the `lab1` data with new `$first_name`

Comment: Yes, lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4 and lab5 old data remains and I get a new list of names after the old data. It's set up in a loop and pulls a long list of names from the database. Using your suggestion I get an old list of names and a new list of names.

Comment: I don't understand what you have done. Can you update your question with what else you have done ?

Comment: I used setText and my query to pull from the database.` lab1.setText(myRs.getString("first_name") + " "+ myRs.getString("last_name"));`

Comment: Why pull from the database ? Just use `lab1.setText($first_name);`. Get the values directly from the textbox. After that, remove the values from the textboxes of your left panel.